# How dangerous for the human skin are naturally occurring wavelengths above 380nm?

Tags: dermatology, aging, sun-exposure

I read on https://www.cancer.org/cancer/cancer-causes/radiation-exposure/uv-radiation.html:

> UVA rays have the least energy among UV rays. These rays can cause skin cells to age and can cause some indirect damage to cells' DNA. UVA rays are mainly linked to long-term skin damage such as wrinkles, but they are also thought to play a role in some skin cancers.

How dangerous are naturally occurring wavelengths above 380nm?